# how to remove shape and body after a delay in collision callback (cocos2d-chipmunk)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

can anyone help me to remove shape and body after a delay in collision callback.

By using cpSpaceAddPostStepCallback(sapce, (cpPostStepFunc)postStepRemove, blockShape, NULL);
i could safely remove the shape .
But i need some delay before i call the function.
I play an animation once the collision in detected.
At the end of the code i need to remove the shape.
Can anyone please help me with some sample code.
The code that i have written is as follows.

```
int collisionSapusBlock(cpArbiter *arb, struct cpSpace *sapce, void *data)
{

cpShape *sapusShape, *blockShape;
cpArbiterGetShapes(arb, &sapusShape, &blockShape);

cpBody *BlockBody = blockShape->body;
cpBody *sapusBody = sapusShape->body;

CCNode *parent = (CCNode*)data;

if (cpvlength(sapusBody->v) > 45)
{
NSLog(@"Collision2 called %f",cpvlength(sapusBody->v));
CCSprite *sprite = blockShape->data;
[parent removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];

///////
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Block2.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *sheet1 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Block2.png" capacity:2];
[parent addChild:sheet1];

CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
CCSprite *sapusSprite1 = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"Block2001.png"];
CCAnimation *sapusAnim = [[CCAnimation alloc] initWithName:@"select" delay:0.15f];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2001.png"]];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2002.png"]];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2003.png"]];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2004.png"]];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2005.png"]];
[sapusAnim addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"Block2006.png"]];
[sapusSprite1 addAnimation: sapusAnim];
[sheet1 addChild:sapusSprite1];

CCAnimate *animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation: sapusAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
[sapusSprite1 runAction:animate];

blockShape->data = sapusSprite1;

/////here after playing the animation i need to delete the blockShape. Help plzzz
}

return 1;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with some sample code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it should work.  In the collision handler, kick off the animation as part of a sequence and then execute the postStepCallback as the last item in the sequence:

```
CCSequence *finalSeq = [CCSequence actions:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:sapusAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
     [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeCpShapeAndBody)], nil];
[sapusSprite1 runAction:finalSeq];
```

Then you'd create a method called removeCPShapeAndBody which would call cpSpaceAddPostStepCallback.  Ideally you'd have all of this in an object that would hold reference to the shape and body (e.g. a subclass of CCSprite) so you don't have to pass those around.